# Custom dynamically created Menus producing some strange errors

Tags: c#, asp.net, aspmenu

The background is I have a custom control that is a asp:Menu that is linked to an xmldatasource.  The xmldatasource is created dynamically depending on the user privies.  Here is the load event for the custom control:

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string userId = (string)Session["userId"];

        if (userId != null)
        {
            DataSet ds = dal.RetrieveApplications(userId);
            ds.DataSetName = "Menus";
            ds.Tables[0].TableName = "Menu";
            DataRelation relation = new DataRelation
            ("ParentChild",
                ds.Tables["Menu"].Columns["Folder_Id"],
            ds.Tables["Menu"].Columns["Parent_Folder_ID"], true);

            relation.Nested = true;
            ds.Relations.Add(relation);


            xmlDataSource1.Data = ds.GetXml();

        }
}
```

This works perfectly for the first user that uses it.  But it seems that every subsequent user is actually getting the first user's menu.  I have walked it through and verified that my dataset is getting created fine and when I examine the XMLDatasource.data at the end of the load the xml is correct.

I am really stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer and though I would leave it out here for others who might search for this:

But I had to set the "ENABLECACHING" to false on the xmldatasource.